# How to debug an unsigned Java Plugin in Firefox using icedtea-7-plugin

Tags: java, plugins, firefox-addon, icedtea

I am new to Stack Exchange and this is my first question so please forgive me if I do not ask this question conforming to the normal standards of this website.  If you have any tips that will help me become a more efficient member please feel free to let me know.

First off, I am having a problem with my Java plugin in Firefox.  Under tools, add-ons, I have listed for my Java plugin, "Java(TM) Plug-in 10.51.2 10.51.2".  I recently installed some updates and apparently the new version of Java automatically blocks un-signed applets from being able to run even if you attempt to allow it manually by clicking on the "Allow Now" option that is displayed in the URL bar.  This is unacceptable as I am currently trying to test software and I need to be able to run the applet.

So to get back to the question, how can I remove that specific Java plugin (Java(TM) Plug-in 10.51.2 10.51.2) and install the icedtea-7-plugin for Firefox to use in its place.  I have installed the icedtea-7-plugin via terminal through the "sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin" command with success but how can I get Firefox to use this plugin and disregard the plugin that is currently listed under the add-ons option in my browser.  Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is a frustrating matter.  Thank you very much!

-Dave

**EDIT:** It is important to note the reason that the OP was asking about allowing unsigned applets was that he is developing on one. This question is therefore on topic as it is about a tool used for software development.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using a Debian (derived) distribution, use [update-java-alternatvies](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java).

You should be able to use -

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

or (for just the browser plug-in) -

```
sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-javaplugin.so
```

Comment: The second option for updating the browser plug-in worked.  I was able to change the plug-in to IcedTeaPlugin.so and now I am able to run my java applet.  Thank you very much for your help!